# Sencha Cmd 6 does not work on CentOS 7

Tags: extjs, centos7, sencha-cmd

I cannot make sencha cmd work on CentOS 7. After installing I try to lunch:

```
sencha -sdk ~/EXTJS/ext-6.0.0 generate app -classic MyApp /home/boooch/test/
```

Output:

```
Sencha Cmd v6.0.2.14
[INF] Copying framework to /home/boooch/test/ext
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
[INF] Using GPL Version of Ext JS version 6.0.0.640 from /home/boooch/test/ext.
[INF] The implications of using GPL version can be found here (http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/licensing).
[INF] Starting server on port : 1841
[INF] Mapping http://localhost:1841/~cmd to /root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.0.2.14...
[INF] Mapping http://localhost:1841/ to /home/boooch/test...
[INF] Application available at http://localhost:1841
[INF] Loading app json manifest...


/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.0.2.14/sencha: line 446:  4314 Killed              $INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX "$app_java_home/bin/java" -server -Dinstall4j.jvmDir="$app_java_home" -Dexe4j.moduleName="$prg_dir/$progname" "-Dinstall4j.launcherId=159" "-Dinstall4j.swt=false" "$vmov_1" "$vmov_2" "$vmov_3" "$vmov_4" "$vmov_5" $INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS -classpath "$local_classpath" com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher launch 6b5f63d9 "" "" com.sencha.command.Sencha "$@"
```

If I try now to build app:

```
cd /home/boooch/test
```

the same issue:

```
Sencha Cmd v6.0.2.14
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
[INF] Using GPL Version of Ext JS version 6.0.0.640 from /home/boooch/test/ext.
[INF] The implications of using GPL version can be found here (http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/licensing).
[INF] Starting server on port : 1841
[INF] Mapping http://localhost:1841/~cmd to /root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.0.2.14...
[INF] Mapping http://localhost:1841/ to /home/boooch/test...
[INF] Application available at http://localhost:1841
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Appending content to /home/boooch/test/bootstrap.js
[INF] Writing content to /home/boooch/test/bootstrap.json
/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.0.2.14/sencha: line 446:  4451 Killed              $INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX "$app_java_home/bin/java" -server -Dinstall4j.jvmDir="$app_java_home" -Dexe4j.moduleName="$prg_dir/$progname" "-Dinstall4j.launcherId=159" "-Dinstall4j.swt=false" "$vmov_1" "$vmov_2" "$vmov_3" "$vmov_4" "$vmov_5" $INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS -classpath "$local_classpath" com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher launch 6b5f63d9 "" "" com.sencha.command.Sencha "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I found issue. My server is KVM with 512 Mb memory. I found answer in dmesg log:

```
[12984.071749] Out of memory: Kill process 6633 (java) score 640 or sacrifice child
[12984.075758] Killed process 6633 (java) total-vm:3091320kB, anon-rss:330116kB, file-rss:0kB
```

If I change java version from 1.8 to 1.7 error became more informative :

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 104988672 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/jvm-6148/hs_error.log
```

In my case solution was to add swap file. How to do this:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-centos-7

and  this: 
https://github.com/sebastian-philipp/btrfs-swapon